# How to get a function from a string?

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, traditional-form, return-value

I'm trying to create a function that takes in input a function written as string and the return it applying a ToExpression and an Evaluate (Code below).
The goal of this function is to transform the function, written inside a string, into a Mathematica expr.

```
FunctionFromStr[strF_] :=
        Module[{expF,f},
            expF = ToExpression[strF, TraditionalForm]
            f[x_] = Evaluate[expF]
            Return[f]
]
```

This code doesn't work, if I try it I get

```
g = FunctionFromString["x+1"]
g[1]
```

FunctionFromString["x+1"]

What can I do to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the community.
With little generalization (be applied to any variable name), Here is how you can achieve your goal:

Since `Function` has `HoldAll` attribute, you have to evaluate its arguments first:

```
ClearAll[FunctionFromString];

FunctionFromString[str_, vars_] := 
 Function[Evaluate[ToExpression[Characters[vars]]], 
  Evaluate[ToExpression[str]]]
```

##### Result

```
g = FunctionFromString["x+1", "x"];

g[1]
(* Out: 2 *)

g /@ Range[5]
(* Out: {2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

It works with multiple variables:

```
g2 = FunctionFromString["x+y", "xy"];

g2[3, 5]
(* Out: 8 *)
```

I should also point out that using `ToExpression` should come with security considerations if you want to apply it to inputs you don't have control over.